# Seam 2.2 with jboss 5 non ejb can't inject entityManager

Tags: jboss, seam, pojo, entitymanager

ETA an explanation of what this is supposed to do.
An employee has to keep track of 2 weeks worth of activities.

Each week(tqiActivitySheetActionBean) contains 7 days (tqiDayActionBean).

Each day contains tasks for that day(tqiTasks)

Tasks are displayed one week at a time(so the employee can switch between this week and last week).

What I did was use an enum to iterate over the week - creates a dataTable of tqiActivitySheetActionBeans and iterate over those in a nested dataTable.

The employee needs to be able to add, delete and edit tasks for each day in place(in the dataTable).  I wrapped the tqiTasks in the tqiDayActionBean to group them.

I posted this over at the Seam website, but I'm not getting any bites, I've tried everything I know and some stuff I don't to get this working, but so far no joy.
There's configuration information for Jboss 5 using EJB's, Jboss 4 without. I have an exploded WAR using Jboss 5 and Seam 2.2.0, and no EJB's.  I cannot inject an entityManager into my action POJOs.
I tried removing the persistence-unit-ref-name reference from web.xml, added and removed

```
<transaction:entity-transaction /> 
<transaction:ejb-transaction />
```

tags from components.xml (with and without entity-manager="#{entityManager}") .   The app won't load when I use either of these.
Used the default values and hardcoded them one at a time. I still can't get this to work.
I'm currently using this configuration:

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="myEmployee" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/myEmployeeDatasource</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
         <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MY_PROD"/>
         <!-- Only relevant if Seam is loading the persistence unit (Java SE bootstrap) -->
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
<!-- this binds emf to jndi under java namespace - but only for jboss prior to 5.0 - I shouldn't need this. -->
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/EntityManagerFactories/myEmployee"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

components.xml:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/EntityManagerFactories/myEmployee"
auto-create="true"/>
```

This deploys and starts correctly, but entityManager is still null.

I have a bunch of EntityHome classes in the same package, these can use an entityManager with no problem. All the docs I've looked at state that I should be able to inject an entityManager, I've followed the configuration info from the Seam docs page, the Seam in Action book and the Seam wiki for JBoss 5 ([Seam wiki](http://code.google.com/p/seaminaction/wiki/DeployingToJBossAS5))

I've set breakpoints in the ManagedPersistence class - where it looks like I have an entityManager right up to the time I want to use it, added @Transactional annotations to the class and method.  Still nothing.  I can get an EM using

```
(EntityManager)Component.getInstance("entityManager")
```

But then I have no transactional access to the underlying entityBean and end up with hibernate LazyInitializationExceptions.
I've been using Seam for almost a year now and I have yet to get this to work.  Up til now using the Component method has worked, but There must be something fundamentally wrong with our setup that I cannot get injection to work.
I'd appreciate any help.

ETA code for user classes.

The entity class is TQITask.  TQIDayActionBean class is supposed to handle the CRUD for a group of TQITasks for one day, TQIActivitySheetActionBean handles the TQIDayActionBeans for one week.

entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TQI_TASK")
@Name("tqitask")
public class TqiTask implements java.io.Serializable {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TqiTask.class);
    private Integer sysid;
    private TqiActivitySubtype tqiActivitySubtype;
    private TqiActivityType tqiActivityType;
// ... more fields, getters and setters
```

dayActionBean(a days tasks):

```
@Name("tQIDayActionBean")
@Transactional(TransactionPropagationType.REQUIRED) //this is latest attempt
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class TQIDayActionBean implements Serializable {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TQIDayActionBean.class);


    @In(required=true)
    EntityManager entityManager;
//this doesn't work either
        @DataModel("tqiTasksForOneDay")
    @Out(required = false)
    private List<TqiTask> tqiTasksForOneDay;

// .... more stuff
// method that should get an entityManager
/**
     * tasks are children of tqiActivitySheet, info we need is in tqiActivitySheetV, so use peopleSoftIdSelected and weekSelected.weekSysid
     * to get the tqiActivitySheet sysid needed to load the right tasks
     *  TODO for now lets just get it straight from the db
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Begin(flushMode=FlushModeType.MANUAL)
    public void generateTasksForDayOfWeek() {
        log.debug("date to search for: " + this.tqiTaskDate);

        this.tqiTasksForOneDay = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t from TqiTask t  where t.workDate = ?1 AND t.activitySheetSysid = ?2 order by t.sysid")
        .setParameter(1, this.tqiTaskDate).setParameter(2, this.activitySheetSysid).getResultList();
    }

getter/setters etc ...
```

activitySheetActionBean(a week's dayActionBeans):

```
/**
 * handle the activity sheet weekly code generation here
 */
@Name("tqiActivitySheetActionBean")
public class TQIActivitySheetActionBean implements Serializable{
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TQIActivitySheetActionBean.class);

// tried it here first  
//  @In
//  EntityManager entityManager;


    @Out(value="tqiDayActionBeansForTheWeek", required=false)
    List<TQIDayActionBean> tqiDayActionBeansForTheWeek;

//  List<DaysOfTheWeek> daysOfTheWeekEnum;

    private BigDecimal currentlySelectedWeekActivitySheetSysid;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        log.debug("calling init");
        this.tqiDayActionBeansForTheWeek = new ArrayList<TQIDayActionBean>();
        this.updateDataWhenWeekChanges();
    }
 getters/setters more stuff ....
```

Comment: Please, post the code of the class where you get entityManager injected as null and how you use this class.

Comment: done, I thought maybe the "new" tqiDayActionBean in init was causing the problem, but I can't inject that either.

Comment: Do you have any other components where the injection of the entity manager worked? How do you call the `TQIActivitySheetActionBean`? Have you tried `@In(create=true)`?

Comment: @kraftan the only place I can use an entityManager without using Component.getInstance() is in the classes that extend EntityHome.  I've tried using create=true.  TQIActivitySheetActionBean is accessed by the view:`<rich:dataTable id="daysOfWeek" var="_daysOfWeek" value="#{tqiActivitySheetActionBean.tqiDayActionBeansForTheWeek}">`

Answer (score 1):

The bean named `tQIDayActionBean` of class `TQIDayActionBean` cannot be instantiated with `new`, and there is absolute no way to have a `List<TQIDayActionBean>` in the application.

This bean, like any other Seam managed bean, can only be injected with `@In` or instantiated with `Component.getInstance()`. In the second case (that is with `Component.getInstance()`) you should understand that Seam will always return the same instance as far as you stay in the context boundaries (in this case until the conversation ends).

I suggest that you rework your code in order to separate a `TQIDay` standard class (without `@Name` and `@Inject`) to model the data you need to manage and collect in multiple instances, from an `TQIActionBean` where you can have your `EntityManager` injected.

Comment: Thank you Stefano, can you expand on your last paragraph?  If I create a standard class won't I have the same problem?  A TQIDayActionBean manages a group of tqiTasks(an entity class).  tqiTasks has relationships with other entities so even if I could create the em in TQIActivitySheetActionBean (which I can't, I tried that first, it's commented out in that class) how would I avoid the LazyInitializationExceptions when the associated entities aren't connected (I get these when I use Component.Instance unless I use FetchType.EAGER in tqiTask for connected fields)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to follow all your application logic. Provided that you don't try to create multiple instance of a Seam bean and don't instantiate it with new, if you have your component conversation scoped you won't have LIE. Also make sure that you start the conversation. Try with <begin-conversation join="true"/> in yourpage.page.xml.

Comment: Sorry, it's entirely possible I'm going about this all wrong.  I added an explanation of what this evilness is supposed to do at the top.